I only have one Google Tag Manager ID set in my Google Tag Manager plugin; but there are two showing in the DOM
I have a WordPress site using the Google Tag Manager plugin.
I have a valid Google Tag Manager ID, My container code is set to ON, and I have chosen "Manually code" in Container code compatibility mode:

I have entered the provided code snippet under after the opening <body> tag in the /themes/Divi-Child/header.php file like this:
/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/header.php
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php if ( function_exists( 'gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag' ) ) { gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag(); } ?>

When I inspect the DOM, I see the ID for the Google Tag directly under the body (the id is marked over in RED in this screenshot), but I also see another Google Tag below that one (id is marked out in BLUE). I am not sure where this other ID is coming from and I would like to remove it. Any thoughts on where this could be?


First of all, loading unknown GTM on your site is a very serious security breach since the owner of that GTM can deploy virtually anything to your pages via it. That's like a backdoor to your front-end.
Check your template files, and check your WP extensions. Look for the other ID. It's probably faster to just do the file search for that id unless they obfuscate it.
Another approach would be disabling plugins one by one or trying to change the theme.
Noscript does almost nothing in the case of GTM except polluting your DOM by its existence. You should be more concerned about <script> instances of GTM.

Thanks for the reply and the information. By "WP extensions", do you mean Plugins? I have searched through all of the files in the project and have only seen that tag in a SQL file. I changed the value of the tag to the new tag that I want to use, saved, emptied cache, and I still see the old tag. I don't think it is explicitly hard-coded in the project, but may instead by obfuscated, like you mentioned. I haven't tried disabling the plugins yet.

Yeah, WP plugins and themes are notorious for doing that. Mostly because WP is usually used by inexperienced webmasters, so it becomes a great opportunity to abuse the trust.

Is this something that might be handled through Google Tag Manager? The actual Tag Manager account, I mean? I don't have access to that (yet), but I'm wondering if I could fix this on that side of things?

Theoretically, a tag manager can deploy another tag manager, but it happens so rarely that I didn't even think of it. You can test it though. Use devtools ability to block network requests and block everythig that contains "gtm" in it. That will prevent GTM from loading, so then check your DOM again and confirm that you still see both GTMs in there. If you do, that means they're not deployed by GTM.
